# Angular 2 | cannot assign to array because it is a constant or a read-only property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a get request to my backend api that returns a array of objects. I'm using following code:

**small.component.ts**
(when calling openDepositModal() it calls the function **getUserInventory()** from auth.service.ts which makes a get request to my backend api that then returns an array with objects.)

```
[...]

export class Item{
    id: String;
    name: String;
    img: String;
    value: String;
}

const items: Item[] = [];

[...]

openDepositModal(){
    if(!items){
        this.authService.getUserInventory().subscribe(data => {
            items = data; <-- ERROR HERE
        });
    }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
[...]

getUserInventory(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/user/inventory', { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json());
}

[...]
```

Inside of small.component.ts I am trying to insert the data I got from the service into the "items" array. But I get the error "cannot assign to array because it is a constant or a read-only property". Can someone fix my code? Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `let` instead of `const`

e.g. `let items: Item[] = [];`

`const` declarations are like `let` declarations but, as their name implies, their value cannot be changed once they are bound. In other words, they have the same scoping rules as let, but you can’t re-assign to them.

> [let vs. const (docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)
>
> Given that we have two types of declarations with similar scoping
> semantics, it’s natural to find ourselves asking which one to use.
> Like most broad questions, the answer is: it depends.
>
> Applying the principle of least privilege, all declarations other than
> those you plan to modify should use const. The rationale is that if a
> variable didn’t need to get written to, others working on the same
> codebase shouldn’t automatically be able to write to the object, and
> will need to consider whether they really need to reassign to the
> variable. Using const also makes code more predictable when reasoning
> about flow of data.
>
> On the other hand, let is not any longer to write out than var, and
> many users will prefer its brevity. The majority of this handbook uses
> let declarations in that interest.

Answer (score 0):

Replace error by `this.items = data;`

Comment: Doesn't work, since the items array is outside of the component class

Answer (score 0):

because you have declared it as an constant. declare it as a property in your class and then you can assign values to it

```
export class SmallComponent{
private items: Item[] = [];

[...]

openDepositModal(){
    if(!items){
        this.authService.getUserInventory().subscribe(data => {
            this.items = data; <-- HERE
        });
    }
}
```

If they are outside of component class then change `const` to `let`